# Will updating macOS from SL to El-Cap cause problems after disabling discrete GPU permanently from EFI (EFI mod and resistor removal)?

Tags: macos, startup, snow-leopard, upgrade

Currently on Macbook Pro 2011 17" 10.6.8 which was resurrected using the resistor-removal mod from "Realmacmods" as well as their EFI script.

Would like to upgrade to El Capitan. Will i run into issues with the kexts/efi changes once I upgrade? Worried it will boot to a black screen.